# Updates to Tour - Community Description Blurb

Tags: discussion, tour

On the [tour page](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) there is a brief description of the community that current reads:

> **Hardware Recommendations** Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people seeking specific hardware recommendations. It's built and run by you as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about hardware recommendations.

How do we want to modify this to better describe the community?

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following:

> **Hardware Recommendations** Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people seeking specific hardware recommendations and information that will lead to such a recommendation. It's built and run by you as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to give a recommendation for every need.

*This answer has been made a community wiki. Please edit it as you see fit. Once we have moderators appointed, they will be able to utilize this answer to update the page.*